# Ошибка No index used in query/prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, php7

При `report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL;` и обычном запросе (`select * from ...`)  вылетает ошибка.

> No index used in query/prepared statement

Решение переключить `report_mode`, а так же вопрос [...'No index used in query/prepared statement'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580039/fatal-error-uncaught-exception-mysqli-sql-exception-with-message-no-index-us) видел. Вопрос в том **почему она появляется?** Ведь поле с первичным ключом содержит индекс или я ошибаюсь? Как можно исправить эту ошибку? (не трогая rep_mod)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> вылетает ошибка.
>
> > No index used in query/prepared statement

Это:

1. Не ошибка
2. Означает не то, что индексов нет, а то, что при выполнении запроса сервер их не использует, сканируя таблицу.

Не-использование индексов при выполнении запроса - в общем вполне штатное событие. Возможно, подходящего (или вообще) индекса нет. Но возможно, что использование индекса менее эффективно, чем прямое сканирование таблицы (в среднем если избирательность вторичного индекса хуже 5-7% - это именно так).

Если это событие интерпретируется PHP именно как ошибка (с визгами и прерыванием исполнения) - то этот состояние сродни багу. На каждый запрос индексов не наделаешь...

Comment: это не "баг" а каприз аффтара, который "не трогая rep_mod". что хочите - то и получите